# Kafka connect cluster properties

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm very new to Kafka and I'm still acquiring some knowledge. I have an **Ecs-Ec2** cluster with **Kafka Connect** with the structure below:

```
├── bitbucket-pipelines.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── env.sh 
├── jmx-kafka-connect-config.yml
├── password.properties
├── rest-jaas.properties
├── task-definition.json
├── worker.properties
```

In my **Dockerfile** I run `COPY` to replace the `properties` files I work on and `CMD connect-standalone /etc/kafka-connect/worker.properties` to start.

> I have two questions.

1. In some tutorials, the settings are very different. They are passed by environment variables. Is my way of working correct or do I need to correct this?
2. I'm running `connect-standalone`, but I've read that to scale I need to work with `connect-distributed`. How can I adjust this to have at least 3 workers working on the same topic? It would be a way of having H.A.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  kafka-connect:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8085:8085"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.4.0

RUN confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:2.1.4 --no-prompt
RUN confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:14.0.8 --no-prompt

USER root

RUN microdnf -y install vim

COPY jmx-kafka-connect-config.yml /etc/kafka-connect/jmx-kafka-connect-config.yml
COPY jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.18.0.jar /etc/kafka-connect/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar
COPY worker.properties /etc/kafka-connect/worker.properties
COPY password.properties /etc/kafka-connect/password.properties
COPY rest-jaas.properties /etc/kafka-connect/rest-jaas.properties

ENV KAFKA_JMX_PORT=1976
ENV KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka-connect/rest-jaas.properties -javaagent:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8085:/etc/kafka-connect/jmx-kafka-connect-config.yml"

EXPOSE 8083
EXPOSE 8085

RUN sed -i 's|log4j.rootLogger=INFO|log4j.rootLogger=ERROR|g' /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties

CMD connect-standalone /etc/kafka-connect/worker.properties
```

**env.sh** - *Run through Bitbucket-pipeline*

```
#!/bin/sh
touch worker.properties

echo bootstrap.servers=$KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS >> worker.properties
echo confluent.license=$CONFLUENT_LICENSE >> worker.properties
echo connector.client.config.override.policy=All >> worker.properties
echo consumer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN >> worker.properties
echo consumer.sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="\"$KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME\"" password="\"$KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD\"";" >> worker.properties
echo consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL >> worker.properties
echo producer.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN >> worker.properties
echo producer.sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="\"$KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME\"" password="\"$KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD\"";" >> worker.properties
echo producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL >> worker.properties
echo sasl.mechanism=PLAIN >> worker.properties
echo sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="\"$KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME\"" password="\"$KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD\"";" >> worker.properties
echo security.protocol=SASL_SSL >> worker.properties
echo group.id=sv-connect >> worker.properties
echo config.storage.topic=sv-connect-configs >> worker.properties
echo offset.storage.topic=sv-connect-offsets >> worker.properties
echo status.storage.topic=sv-connect-status >> worker.properties
echo key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter >> worker.properties
echo value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter >> worker.properties
echo internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter >> worker.properties
echo internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter >> worker.properties
echo offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/offset.txt >> worker.properties
echo rest.extension.classes=org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension >> worker.properties
echo log4j.root.loglevel=WARN >> worker.properties
echo log4j.loggers=org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR >> worker.properties
echo config.storage.replication.factor=3 >> worker.properties
echo offset.storage.replication.factor=3 >> worker.properties
echo status.storage.replication.factor=3 >> worker.properties
echo plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components >> worker.properties
echo kafka.jmx.port=1976 >> worker.properties
echo kafka.opts=-javaagent:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8085:/etc/kafka-connect/jmx-kafka-connect-config.yml >> worker.properties

touch password.properties
echo "$KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME: $KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD" >> password.properties
```

Comment: Were you able to successfully run the Kafka Connect on ECS? I am using Fargate and having issue reading environment variables inside the properties file. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but I don't use Fargate! I created a script and called it in the dockerfile.

Comment: **Dockerfile** `COPY scripts/set_env.sh /etc/set_env.sh` and `CMD ["/etc/set_env.sh"]
`

Comment: **script** 

`#!/bin/bash
set -x

export TASK=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

echo $TASK

CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=$TASK /etc/confluent/docker/run`

Comment: This might help you [kafka-connect-distributed-mode-dockerfile](https://forum.confluent.io/t/kafka-connect-distributed-mode-dockerfile/4760)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They are passed by environment variables

You could use `kafka-connect-base` image, by the way since the connectors you're using don't require a license, but yes, they use Jinja templates to define the config.

There is no reason to copy your own, really, especially if they are all static values anyway (not dependent on other environment variables, such as an AWS region that could be determined at runtime).

- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka-connect-base/include/etc/confluent/docker/configure#L54
- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka-connect-base/include/etc/confluent/docker/kafka-connect.properties.template

> I'm running connect-standalone

The image does not run this. It defaults to `connect-distributed.sh` correctly, so don't override the ENNTYPOINT / CMD, and you're fine. Just scale the ECS replicas.

Note: You could also use EKS and run Strimzi there with KafkaConnect k8s resources, which offers much more useful features, including built-in JMX monitoring and alerting features.

> least 3 workers working on the same topic?

This is controlled by `tasks.max`, not the workers. I.e. setting to three for the ElasticSink would start three Kafka Consumer threads in parallel and read from at least 3 topic partitions in one consumer group. If you have less partitions in the topic, then you'd have idle tasks.